# TypeError while trying to copy json data js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, typeerror

i'm new on javascript and also working with json. i'm trying to get some json data and store some of them in `keepGetData`. but when I want to get an entry, it says `TypeError`.
what is wrong with my code?

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'keepGetData[j] =
>   result[i]')

thanks in advance

```
var keepGetData; 
function getList(){
$.getJSON(url, function(result){
var j=0;
for(var i=0,len=result.length;i<len;i++){
if(result[i].parentId == 1 && result[i].restaurantId == restId.id[0]
{
keepGetData[j] = result[i];   
j+=1;
}
}
});
```

Comment: Have you tried var keepGetData = [];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your variable:

```
 var keepGetData = [];
```

Please do use strict mode by writing "use strict" in the first line of your Javascript files. That catches the use of uninitialized variables much easier.

Comment: We all have to start somewhere :) If the answer helped you, please accept it - I gain some points and others who stumble upon it via google see the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
var keepGetData=[];
```

You should use above code.You need to define the variable as array.